# Appengine API calls: Application restrictions: HTTP referrers (websites) or IP addresses (web servers, cron jobs, etc.)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, api-key

How to set the restrictions on a Google API key when accessing an API with URL fetch call from an appengine backend?

Options:

1. HTTP referrers: https://[projectID].appspot.com without any luck.
2. IP Address: Not sure what appengine IP address is? Wouldn't it change?

[image: API Key restrictions]

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do and what problems you've run into. I kind of have an idea, but it would help to be more concrete.

Comment: What restrictions? You want to restrict the source (who's allow to use the key) or the scope (what the key is allowed to access) or restrict the usage (how often is the key allowed to access)?

It seems like you are look for authentication, is that what you are looking for? If the key is in your code, how do you determine who's using your app? Can't you implement application-level authentication?

Comment: Only my appengine backend should be authorized to make API calls using this key.  It's is never active on any client side code.  Therefore I should be able to restrict API calls to only the Google Appengine servers. I'm just not sure what the correct HTTP referrer to use for my key is. -- Screen Shot added

Comment: Have you figured it out? My thought is it's not possible. Best to just protect your key and rotate it on a regular basis.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the App Engine IP addresses, please check the IP address part of the [App Engine knowledge base](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/). App Engine uses a block of IP address, so you will need to allow all of them.

You should be able to use your HTTP referrer if your app makes the HTTP API call with the key (such a making a GET request to an API with the key in the parameters).

Please check out all the details on the [restrictions here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#api_key_restrictions) for references.

Comment: restricting based on IP address seems unlikely and not really useful as another appengine app could potentially use my key.

Comment: The referrer part should work. Please edit the post with your code.